# How to escape the non english character at server side

Tags: java, javascript, internationalization

My machine supports several language other than english e.g Chinese, Hindi & German.

I have a web application which sends `escape(innerHTML)` from the client to server where innerHTML contents are written to a file at server side. It's working fine and there isn't any issue if the all charcters are in english.
But If any character is/are in non-english language i am getting exception at server side.

```
var innerHTML = escape (document.getElementBYId("id_1").innerHTML); 
  let suppose,  
     innerHTML = escape("<div id="test"> <p> 
                             There are some text in english  </p> </div>);

now i use AJAX to send this innerHTML to server and it works correctly.
```

above example is working if all chracter are in english but if the any chracter is in lets say Hindi, i am getting exception at server side

```
 let suppose,
         innerHTML = escape ( "<div id="test"> <p> 
                                    some text in **** hindi </p>  </div>");
   now, i send this via ajax function to the server but getteing error.
```

please give me any better idea to solve this issue. Should i apply `internationalization` at client and server side as well ? or only at server side ?

**Exception i am getting at server side : **

```
Dec 21, 2011 4:55:15 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters processParameters

WARNING: Parameters: Character decoding failed. Parameter 'innerHTML' with value '
```

Comment: Just send the raw data to the server and let it handle it. You should not count on client side script to do such things as it can be disabled and even worse, spoofed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ok. i use only `escape` to ignore the special character at client side and sending the raw data. but it fails at server if any chracter is non-english.

Comment: If you send without the `escape` does it work without error?

Comment: then it gives error at client side and doesn't pass the special character without `escape` that is why i am using the escape to surpass the client side error.

Comment: `special character means  : <, >, ", /, ', etc...`

Comment: You still didn't explain what you do on server-side. What gives the exception?

Comment: @Dr.Molle, sorry. please take a look again. i explained the error..

Comment: Post the AJAX code you're using to send the data and maybe we can help you fix it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Dr. Molle is very much correct. almost resolved now. thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using encodeURIComponent() instead of escape()

Also be sure that the page is UTF8-encoded to be able to handle different languages.

Comment: great Dr. Molle. I think the problem was at client side while i was thinking about server side. now i don't get any exception but the character published (written to file) meaningless.

Comment: How do you write to the file, is the file you write to UTF8-encoded as well?

Comment: Dr. Molle you are very much correct, the file i was writting it wasn't UTF8 encoded and almost resolved now.